# SubSonic configuration - how to ignore certain tables

Tags: configuration, subsonic

In the database I have about 150 tables - most of them from previous versions of the application I currently work on.
For my app I only need about 20 tables - is there a way to ignore some of the tables by setting some parameter in web.config?

Answer (score 4):

suppose you have tables with names Table1, Table2, Table3 and you want to use only Table1 and Table3

You can use **excludeTableList** or **includeTableList** attributes to control this.

*includeTableList*

```
<add name="YourProvider" type="SubSonic.SqlDataProvider, SubSonic" 
 connectionStringName="YourConnection" 
 generatedNamespace="YourNamespace" includeTableList="Table1, Table3"/>
```

*excludeTableList*

```
<add name="YourProvider" type="SubSonic.SqlDataProvider, SubSonic" 
 connectionStringName="YourConnection" 
 generatedNamespace="YourNamespace" excludeTableList="Table2"/>
```

Usually if you have few table to include you will use **includeTableList** so you have to type fewer names. You can also use * wildcard like this includeTableList="Table*" />

*viewStartsWith*

if your view starts with vw_ you can add following option:

```
viewStartsWith="vw_"
```

Comment: Thanks, but it's now ignoring my views, please see my config section below.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use excludeTableList: [see here](http://subsonicproject.com/configuration/defining-which-tables-and-views-you-want-to-generate-code-for/)

Comment: Thanks, but it's now ignoring my views, please see my config section below.